# How to control what kind of tags / flags are imported with osm2po?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

With the help of osm2po, I have successfully inserted the contents of the italian files (italy.osm.pbf) in a pgrouting-enabled database (postgresql 8.4)

It displays fine in Qgis, using rule based labeling (thanks to underdark for the .qml file).

Now I wonder: how can I find out what attributes are included in the .pbf and how to control what tags / flags are imported in the database? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look into the ***osm2po.config*** file.
There you'll find lines like this one:

```
wtr.tag.highway.motorway = 1, 11, 120
```

(concurrent order, clazz, default speed)

e.g. filter your clazz-column (**clazz=11**) and you'll retrieve all motorways.

concurrent order means, that if osm gives you two main tags for the same street (e.g. highway=residential and railway=rail) that one with the lower value (e.g. 1 vs. 2) will win.

Comment: Hi Carsten, thanks - that helps. Corcurrent order was new to me.Still don't know though what kind of attributes are in the base file and how to control the import

Comment: Your last name sounds german, you can also contact me via email.